# authenticate connection to activeMQ with username/password

Tags: c#, activemq-classic, spring.net, nms

I have an application running ok sending messages to activemq. I'm using spring.net and Nmstemplate to connect to broker.
xml configuration file in general is:

```xml
<object id="ActiveMqConnectionFactory" 
        type="Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.ConnectionFactory, Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ">
</object>

<object id="ConnectionFactory"
        type="Spring.Messaging.Nms.Connections.CachingConnectionFactory, Spring.Messaging.Nms">
  <constructor-arg index="0" ref="ActiveMqConnectionFactory"/>
  <property name="SessionCacheSize" value="10"/>
</object>

<object id="NmsTemplate" 
        type="Spring.Messaging.Nms.Core.NmsTemplate, Spring.Messaging.Nms">
  <constructor-arg index="0" ref="ConnectionFactory"/>
  <property name="MessageConverter" ref="SimpleMessageConverter"/>
</object>

<object id="SimpleMessageConverter" 
        type="Spring.Messaging.Nms.Support.Converter.SimpleMessageConverter, Spring.Messaging.Nms">
</object>
```

Until everything is working find sending message with NmsTemplate.ConvertAndSend();
The problem is that I want to secure connection using username/password.
I setup credentials in activemq configuration file and now I need to supply this credentials in code but I dont find where !!
I tried with:

```xml
<object id="ActiveMqConnectionFactory" type="Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.ConnectionFactory, Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ">
  <property name="UserName" value="usertest"/>
  <property name="Password" value="passwordtest"/>
</object>
```

But when sending I get "Connection already closed" exception, and the same setting credentials in code.

So, anyone have a good example or hint in how to setup username/password to send message to secured activemq broker?

Answer (score 3):

Since no-one has answered this, I found this answer on http://forum.springframework.net/showthread.php?9184-authenticate-to-activeMQ-using-Nmstemplate-in-net

```
this.ConnectionFactory.UserName = this.Username;
this.ConnectionFactory.Password = this.Password;

this.ConnectionFactory.BrokerUri = new System.Uri(this.Uri);

using (IConnection conn = this.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection())
{
using (ISession session = conn.CreateSession())
{
    IObjectMessage objMessage = session.CreateObjectMessage(message);
    using (IMessageProducer producer = session.CreateProducer())
            {
                    NmsDestinationAccessor destinationResolver = new NmsDestinationAccessor();
                    IDestination destination = destinationResolver.ResolveDestinationName(session, this.Queue);
                    producer.Send(destination, objMessage);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it creates a Connection with `userNam`e & `password` then starts it to create as `session` which then used to create a `consumer` which uses `consumer.Receive()` to read a single message form the queue.

```cs
string brokerUri = "broker uri here";
string userName = "someone";
string password = "**********";
string QueueName = "somequeue";

IConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory(new Uri(brokerUri));

//Create Connection
using (var connection =  connectionFactory.CreateConnection(userName,password)
{
    connection.Start(); //Start Connection

    //Creating new session
    using (var session = connection.CreateSession()){
        //Getting the Queue
        var queue = session.GetQueue(config.QueueName);
        
        //Using destination: 
        IDestination destination = Apache.NMS.Util.SessionUtil.GetDestination(session, $"queue://{queue.QueueName}");

        //Create a new consumer
        using (IMessageConsumer consumer = session.CreateConsumer(destination)){
            try{
                // Consume a message
                ITextMessage message = consumer.Receive(timeSpan) as ITextMessage;
                /*Do something here with message*/              
            }
            catch (NMSConnectionException nmex){
                //LogError(nmex.Message, nmex);
            }
            catch (Exception ex){
                log.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```